2000 Ford F150,,parasitic drain question
What causes the radio to come on when reconnecting the battery? Also what could cause a 9.29 amp parasitic drain when parked and all accessories are off? Any replies are greatfull.

Don't know about the battery, but for the drain what I'd start with is pulling fuses while a meter is connected to test for the drain. When you pull the guilty circuit's fuse the drain will stop.

9 amps is a pretty hefty something. I second @mikeb - start pulling fuses (focus on ones that are not switched on with ignition, which does help reduce the number).

If we combine both of your questions and ask "What one thing would cause the radio to come on when I connect the battery AND cause a 9 amp battery drain when parked and accessories off?" then that one thing could be your ignition switch.
An ignition switch as commonly seen in most year 2000 car and truck models has four possible positions:
OFF: No power to anything except constant-on accessories such as clock, interior lights, alarm, etc.
ACC: No power to engine / ignition but everything else should have power, including radio, seat motors, ventilation, etc.
ON or RUN: Everything on including engine / ignition.
START: Engage the starter with ignition on and sometimes disable accessories while the engine cranks.
If your ignition switch is worn out and defective, then while it appears to be in the OFF position, it may be powering accessories or the ignition. If you have a separate power amp or powered subwoofer, this could easily consume 9 amps. So could the ignition, though that would probably turn on the dash lights as well.
Mikeb in a comment suggested removing fuses one at a time and I agree this is the best way to isolate the problem. But don't be tricked into finding fault with the radio if pulling the radio fuse makes the current drain drop; the problem could be the ignition switch instead.

Thanks for the info, Jim
